# How to automate 2D mesh alterations based on edge conditions?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a python script that will take a 2D mesh(or curve if better) that is generate via CAD Sketcher and alter it so that the edge vertexes are offset at various distances based on certain conditions. Here is an example of the input and what I want the script to output.

Input:

[image: 2D mesh input]

Output:

[image: 2D mesh output]

These are exaggerated alterations for easier viewing, but the alterations need to be done in imperial units. The primary conditions for these alterations are:

- at intersections, longest edge is extruded out X inches while the shorter edge is offset X+extra inches
- if edge vertex bisects another edge, ignore length and offset the bisecting edge only leave

The other conditions are the offset amount based on whether edges are exterior(aka boundary) or interior edges.

I thought this would be simple but I'm having an unbelievably hard time with this. I'm not new to coding(primarily MATLAB), but I am new to python with blender and it's incredibly confusing to find the correct methods to do this simple task. I certainly don't expect anyone to code this entire thing for me, but any help would be a godsend.

Also, if possible I would also like to turn each edge(after alterations) into it's own named mesh. i.e. exterior1,exterior2,...,interior1,interior2,...

Comment: You may want to email / open a ticket with the CAD Sketcher developer.  https://www.cadsketcher.com/

Comment: I was only planning on using CAD sketcher to created the 2D meshes and then use bmesh to do the automated edits. I used sketcher for the example images just cause it does a great job of showing exactly what I want to do as far as offsets and conditions for offsets. I'll probably try asking them though. I'm getting pretty desperate at this point lol